# Flutter web complaining about device_info_plus

Tags: flutter-web

I'm getting these logs when I wasn't before (I'm pretty sure):

```
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.2.3/lib/device_info_plus.dart:88:20: Error: Member not found:
'isAndroid'.
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                   ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.2.3/lib/device_info_plus.dart:90:27: Error: Member not found:
'isIOS'.
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                          ^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.2.3/lib/device_info_plus.dart:92:27: Error: Member not found:
'isLinux'.
      } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
                          ^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.2.3/lib/device_info_plus.dart:94:27: Error: Member not found:
'isMacOS'.
      } else if (Platform.isMacOS) {
                          ^^^^^^^
../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.2.3/lib/device_info_plus.dart:96:27: Error: Member not found:
'isWindows'.
      } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
```

`device_info_plus.dart` supports web, but I wonder if this conditional check is failing for some reason:

`import 'dart:io' if (dart.library.html) 'dart:html';`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure flutter supports conditional import ?

Comment: do you sure flutter support conditional import

Answer (score 0):

`flutter pub cache repair` did the job.