# How to switch off unneeded plugin which produce error?

Tags: flutter

How to solve flutter run(build) error:

```
flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus_windows-2.1.1/lib/src/device_info_plus_windows.dart:24:35: Error: Required named parameter
```

'userName' must be provided.
[        ]     final data = WindowsDeviceInfo(

I don't need windows-plugin in the dependencies of device_info_plus plugin.
Flutter doctor all is ok
How to switch off  "device_info_plus_windows" plugin in the project ?

Comment: are you using catcher : ^0.6.9 ?

Comment: I searching solution not able to fix this. I am using MacBook Air M1 chip machine. may be there is issue with this Mac M1?

Comment: after removing the catcher dependency it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about you're using ^ in your library's version in file `pubspec.yaml` which may harm your code if the lib has an update

Just **remove** that ^ and try again

On my side the library that caused the problem is

`device_info_plus` and `flutter_secure_storage`

But, If you have another dependency eg. catcher:^0.6.8 that cannot update the device_info_plus to latest or 4.0.2

so add this to `pubspec.yaml` below dependencies:

dependency_overrides:
device_info_plus: '4.0.0'
device_info_plus_platform_interface: '2.3.0'

[image]

the issue will resolve for me and all of my team.

Answer (score 0):

> flutter/.**pub-cache**/...

Whenever you have problems like these, i.e. *unwanted stuff in your cache*, you need to clean your workspace before compiling again.

Ensure you've removed all of the unwanted dependencies from your `pubspec.yaml`.

Then, in your current working directory (cwd), run:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run
```

This should be enough.

Comment: This approach does not work because in pubspec installed only device_info_plus but error-plugin setuped in the dependencies of device_info_plus.How to disable a non-plugin plugin in its dependencies ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Referring [Flutter web complaining about device_info_plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214223/flutter-web-complaining-about-device-info-plus),
use following command and try to build again.

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue

Worked for me:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get

flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```